# How to split graph data into train and test sets for link prediction problem using node emebbdings and cosine similarity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-distance

I would like to predict new links using node embeddings and cosine similarity, but I am unsure how to split the data set into training and testing, and how to evaluate new links.
This is my code without splitting

creating undirected graph

```py
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edge_list, source='source', target='target', create_using=nx.Graph())
```

here embed nodes

```py
model = node2vec.fit(window=10, min_count=1)
node2vec = Node2Vec(G, dimensions=128, walk_length=40, num_walks=100, workers=2)

emb_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        [model.wv.get_vector(str(node)) for node in G.nodes()],
        index = G.nodes
    )
)
```

And then predict the links using cosine similarity metric

```
def predict_links(G, df, node_id, N):   
 user = df[df.index == node_id]  
all_nodes = G.nodes()
    other_nodes = [node for node in all_nodes if node not in list(G.adj[node_id]) + [node_id]]
    other_users = df[df.index.isin(other_nodes)]
 sim = cosine_similarity(user, other_users)[0].tolist()
    idx = other_users.index.tolist()
 idx_sim = dict(zip(idx, sim))
    idx_sim = sorted(idx_sim.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
similar_users = idx_sim[:N]
    users = [art[0] for art in similar_users]
    return users
```

To conclude, I would like to know how to adjust this code so that a training and testing set is included to learn node embeddings and evaluate the predictions of new links.

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: You could split by time, for example: train on the first 8 years, validate on the 9th year and test on the 10th year.